# Does macOS Sierra run Xcode 7.x?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, compatibility, macos

Is Xcode 7.x functional running macOS Sierra to submit builds to iTunes Connect?

Comment: I really think that it's pointless to ask anything about macOS at the current stage. Anything can be changed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a software beta release. This question is more appropriate for Apple Developer or Community Fora.

Comment: It's useful to know, as it's status changes @slick

Comment: didn't know a better place to post this @IconDaemon. It is mac software after all

Comment: Here ya go! [Apple Developer Forums / Beta / macOS 10.12](https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/beta/macos-1012)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Submitting apps built with beta versions of an OS or beta versions of Xcode are not officially supported, but you can [build apps with a normal version of Xcode on a beta OS](https://georgegarside.com/blog/ios/submit-apps-built-beta-xcode/) by changing the OS version prior to archiving the app inside Xcode.

Comment: thanks for your answer, have you tested it personally? Does it run at all?

Comment: @PedroAlmeida Yes, I have the developer beta installed and it works fine.

Comment: You did this on macOS Sierra? I have tried doing this but I still can't change the system info plist... How are you doing it? I need it asap to patch a bug!

Comment: @Amit You need to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/package-incompatible-installer/) as mentioned in the article.

Comment: I did disable it. I still wasn't able to change the system info plist file. even after making it say read and write access.

Comment: are You sure you using Sierra?

Comment: @Amit Try `sudo nano` on the file. Yes, I'm using Sierra since DP1.

Answer (score 3):

You can't submit anything built with a beta OS or beta Xcode. After it becomes live is the only time Apple will accept it for the Store (not including TestFlight).

Comment: thanks for your answer, have you tested it personally?

Answer (score 0):

Is fully functional when you are in the process of develompent and testing in your own device locally, but is not possible to upload an archive to the itunes connect, to upload it is neccessary use the Application Loader from the XCODE 8 BETA, but only for Testflight, at this momment is not possible to upload a build to the App Store for revision...

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7 is unstable on Sierra. It will run, but crashes and hangs a lot. So much so that it's effectively unusable, which leaves you with two choices. Either upgrading your code base to Xcode 8 (Swift 3), or downgrading OS X to El Capitan.